# What is the difference between a crane pose and a frog tuck?

Tags: form, yoga, gymnastics

[Crane poses](http://www.yogajournal.com/poses/468) are yoga moves:

[image: http://www.yogajournal.com/poses/468]

A frog tuck, as I understand it, is mainly a gymnastics move that's taught as a progression to, among other things, planches:

[image: forg tuck]

Are they pretty much the same thing, just with different names?

I note that in the crane pose pic the persons knees are above the elbow whereas in the frog tuck pic they're below. From what I've read ([writings by Christopher Sommer](http://www.dragondoor.com/articles/building-an-olympic-body-through-bodyweight-conditioning/)) a frog tuck is supposed to have the knees above the elbow so I figure the pic just isn't that great a pic.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't really about health and fitness. What is gained by answering this question?

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr - better understanding of form and technique? Like if they are different and I think they're the same then maybe I'm doing one when I should be doing the other. Also, I think it helps when talking to other people about fitness. Someone with a yoga background wants to get to the point where they can do a planche? Instead of telling them to do a frog tuck when they have no idea what that is I could tell them to do a crane pose. And, in any event, they're yoga and gymnastics moves. I shouldn't tag questions about yoga and gymnastics with those respective tags?

Comment: Also, like let's say you post a question on stackoverflow about how == and === compare. They're similar but not the same and I think a question about how they're different - if they're different at all - is quite relevant. Comparisons help build understanding.

Comment: @neubert "*Someone with a yoga background wants to get to the point where they can do a planche? Instead of telling them to do a frog tuck when they have no idea what that is I could tell them to do a crane pose.*" Then, your question is about instructional technique and terminology, rather than fitness.

Comment: _"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."_ [[Help: Don't ask](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)]

Answer (score 4):

**No, a frog stance and a crane pose are not the same thing.**

That second picture is a terrible example of a frog pose, but the article you linked has a much better one here:

[image]

As you'll notice the big difference is the lack of contact between the knees and the elbows that is in both of the photos you linked. Part of the challenge of the frog stance (and planche) is the ability to hold the core rigid and hold the hips and eventually the legs at a distance. The frog stance trains the core to work against the massive torque generated when the legs are extended in the full planche.

When the legs are brought in contact with the elbows as in the crane pose, the abdominals and hip flexors need to provide much less stability as the upper arms, torso and upper legs build a rigid triangle (although less pronounced in the upper photo) that provides a massive mechanical advantage.

While the crane pose looks similar the change in torque and stability required in the frog pose make them vastly different exercises.